# Spring boot app scale up with mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, microservices

I have created spring-boot app and database using mysql. Then I Dockerised And Deployed it. below show my docker-compse.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  seat_reservation_service:
    image: springio/seat_reservation_service
    ports:
     - "8090:8090"
    environment:
     - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
  seat_reservation_sql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
    - 33306:3306
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=seat-reservation-query
```

this is my spring application.yml file

```
server:
  port: 8090
spring:
  profiles: docker
  main:
    banner-mode: 'off'
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://seat_reservation_sql:3306/seat-reservation-query?useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: root
    validation-query: SELECT 1
    test-on-borrow: true
  jpa:
    show_sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5
    properties:
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: false
          use_query_cache: false
        generate_statistics: false
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /api/
  rabbitmq:
      host: rabbitmq-1
      username: test
      password: password
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: false
    org.hibernate: ERROR
  path: logs/prod/

axon:
  amqp:
    exchange: SeatReserveEvents
  eventhandling:
    processors: 
      statistics.source: statisticsQueue
```

My problem is I need more replicas form `seat_reservation_service` service. If I scale up `seat_reservation_service` that refer same database. According to micro-service architecture I need separate database for each replica. How can I do that?

> if I use in memory database it can do

Comment: Can you clarify if you are looking to scale out MySQL with all master-master relationships or can the `seat_reservation_service` work with a read-only MySQL replica? In both of these cases it is not likely a simple answer. Building any auto-scaling with MySQL (without something like Google Cloud SQL or AWS RDS) is not very trivial.

Answer (score 0):

> According to micro-service architecture I need separate database for each replica. How can I do that?

This "rule" refers to the microservice types, not to the instances of the  same microservice.  So, you can scale separately the `seat_reservation_service` and `seat_reservation_sql`. For example, you could have 4 instances of `seat_reservation_service` and 3 instances of `seat_reservation_sql` (1 master and 2 slaves or a [Galera](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/mariadb-galera-swarm/blob/master/README.md) cluster).